# In WSO2 how to updrade / downgrade subscription tier?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Suppose user subscribed to Api1 with Silver tire. And now user want to upgrade same subscription to Gold tier. How user will do it in wso2 store. Is there any web service available to upgrade this plan/tier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade the subscription directly. Instead, you can [remove current subscription](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/store/#!/operations#SubscriptionIndividual#subscriptionsSubscriptionIdDelete) and [subscribe again](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/store/#!/operations#SubscriptionIndividual#subscriptionsPost) with the new tier.

Comment: This is worst method to do it... Is there any other method to do this? Because its equally important to update same subscription with other tier instead creating new subscription. I will need same subscription id at end for new subscription.

Comment: No, this is the only way, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @Bhathiya for your reply. I am trying to change tireid in subscription table from my custom code. Will it work properly? Is there any other table where it stores subscription in that wso2 API manager or analytics server directly using other than subscription table.

Comment: That's where subscription data is stored. So it should work.